# Did Mirri Maz Dur tell Dany she can't get pregnant in the show?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Ok, there's a very well known part of the story in the books canon where [Mirri Maz Dur](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mirri_Maz_Duur) tells [Daenerys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen) that she is now barren, or at least that's how Dany interprets Mirri's line:

> When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east. When the seas go dry and mountains blow in the wind like leaves. **When your womb quickens again, and you bear a living child.** Then he will return, and not before.
> <sub>A Song of Ice and Fire: Book One - *A Game of Thrones*, Chapter Sixty-Eight ([Daenerys IX](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Game_of_Thrones-Chapter_68)).</sub>

Now in the show, *Game of Thrones*, Dany tells Jon Snow (in the episode *The Dragon and the Wolf*) that she can't get pregnant, to which Jon says "challenge accepted".

The problem is that I don't recall Mirri actually saying the pregnant part to Dany on the show, so **Did Mirri Maz Dur tell Dany she can't have children on the show?** If so, when/where?

If not, then it's time for another question.

---

<sup>Many of us have doubts about the legitimacy of Mirri's 'prophecy':</sup>

- [Are there any proofs of Mirri Maz Duur's curse for Daenerys?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122943/are-there-any-proofs-of-mirri-maz-duurs-curse-for-daenerys)
- [Why does Daenerys trust the prophecies of those who betray her?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70515/why-does-daenerys-trust-the-prophecies-of-those-who-betray-her)

But that's not the point, because Dany believes them.

Comment: She certainly didn't tell Dany in [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5E7kPax4eno), so what on Planetos is going on?

Comment: "Maybe the woman that killed your husband is not a trustful source"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

She didn't tell her in the show.

In the show, this is how it went:

> **Mirri:** You asked for life, you paid for life.
>
> **Daenerys:** This is not life. When will he be as he was?
>
> **Mirri:** When the sun rises in the west, sets in the east. When the seas go dry. When the mountains blow in the wind like leaves.
> <sub>***Season 1 Episode 10 - Fire and Blood***</sub>

We are not alone in spotting that. New York Times [pointed it out as well](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/22/watching/daenerys-targaryen-dragons.html?mcubz=3):

> When Dany confronts Mirri in the show about Drogo’s condition and asks
>   when her Khal will be as he was before, the healer-witch responds with
>   a poetic version of “never”: “When the sun rises in the west and sets
>   in the east. When the seas go dry and the mountains blow in the wind
>   like leaves.” **In the books, she adds one more line, the most crucial
>   line in this fertility crisis: “When your womb quickens again, and you
>   bear a living child.”**

Business Insider [also spotted the hole](http://www.businessinsider.com/game-of-thrones-is-daenerys-infertile-barren-mother-dragons-2017-8):

> "This is not life," Daenerys tells Duur. "When will he be as he was?"
>
> "When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east," Duur said on
>   the show. "When the seas go dry and the mountains blow in the wind,
>   like leaves."
>
> However, **"Game of Thrones" omitted a significant portion of Duur's
>   warning.** Here's what she said in the books:
>
> When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east When the seas go
>   dry and mountains blow in the wind like leaves
>   **When your womb quickens again and you bear a living child Then he will return, and not before.**

As of now it appears that Show-Runners deliberately chose to omit that line in Season 1, probably planning on getting her pregnant and then they forgot all about it in Season 7.

[image]

Or we could just say that Mirri must have cursed Daenerys with infertility off-screen.

Comment: Ahh, off-screen curses, they're said to be the most annoying type!

Comment: Does it count if I curse D&D off-screen?

Comment: @Möoz God knows I do. Doesn't look like it works

Comment: This is speculation, but can "when your womb quickens again and bears a living child" not be interpreted as a figure of speech which basically means "when you fall in love with another and bear his child", which then (karmically, according to Mirri) defeats the purpose of bringing Drogo back as it proves Dany has moved on from Drogo? (and Drogo will not be happy to see her with the other guy, thus he won't come back in a way that Dany would like him to come back)

Comment: @Flater Given the context, I'd say no. She was after all using a long poetic version of plain "Never ever ever ever". But good theory.

Comment: @Aegon: Offtopic for this question, but if you believe Mirri to basically say "never ever ever ever", then she is not being factually correct but rather poetically and gloatfully driving the point home. But then that clashes with [your answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168560/is-quentyn-martell-the-sun-that-rises-in-the-west-and-sets-in-the-east/168563?noredirect=1#comment449477_16856) that argues there is an **actual** prophecy, and that it can be (and according to your answer, it almost **is**) fulfilled.

Comment: @Flater The same answer also mentions that It is a fan theory and Citadel points out that it is unclear that if its a real prophecy or just something Mirri made up to scare Dany. Dany herself however believes it and she never got pregnant after all those tumbles with Daario.

Comment: @Aegon Fair enough. As to Daario, if we consider Dany and Daario to be friends with benefits rather than lovers (which, as far as I've seen Dany respond to Daario, seems to be the case), that means Dany never fell in love (assuming my interpretation of Mirri's words = her womb never quickened).

Comment: They like cutting out the good bits... much like how the Valonqar is cut from Maggie's prophecy to Cersei in the shwo.

Comment: @Skooba It is? Oh well, guess they will need another pair of legs when Cersei meets her demise....`They like cutting out the good bits`, Varys, Theon and Greyworm hate you.

Comment: well my thought is that maybe we won't get it all and she dies in some other way.